# Is there any way to add ui-element, ElMessageBox confirm button click event?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, messagebox, uielement

When I **delete** a data from the table, I want it to pop up a warning in the middle of the screen first.Delete function is ready,i just want to add confirm button click event(delete function) when i pop up ElMessageBox.When I press yes, the deletion should be done.But i couldn't find a way to do it.Any helps? Thanks in advance!

Here is my html code

```
              <el-button class="menu-link px-3" type="text" @click="open">
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3">
              <inline-svg src="media/icons/duotune/art/art005.svg" /> </span
            >&nbsp;Delete
          </el-button>
```

Here is my script code

```
   const open = () => {
    ElMessageBox.confirm(
'Do you want to continue the deletion?',  
{
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  cancelButtonText: 'No',
  type: 'warning',
  center: true,     
})
.then(() => {
  ElMessage({
    type: 'success',
    message: 'Deletion completed',
  })
})
.catch(() => {
  ElMessage({
    type: 'info',
    message: 'Deletion canceled',
  })
})
}
```

Here is my Delete function

```
    const deleteCustomer = (id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < tableData.value.length; i++) {
    if (tableData.value[i].id === id) {
      tableData.value.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
};
```

[You can click to see the screen shot outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op6Q3.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you click yes the `.then()` part of open function gets executed. In that block you need to call the delete function.

You need to pass id to `open()` function as well. Like `open(id)`.

`this.deleteCustomer(id)` or just `deleteCustomer(id)`.

```js
const open = (id) => { // pass the id
    ElMessageBox.confirm(
'Do you want to continue the deletion?',  
{
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  cancelButtonText: 'No',
  type: 'warning',
  center: true,     
})
.then(() => {
  // here you can call the delete function. 
  // this is the part that is executed when you click yes
  this.deleteCustomer(id) // use the id
  ElMessage({
    type: 'success',
    message: 'Deletion completed',
  })
})
.catch(() => {
  ElMessage({
    type: 'info',
    message: 'Deletion canceled',
  })
})
}
```